# how to deliver a variable to stringvar in Tkinter and set own bitmap in title?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I am doing my Graduation Project,and i meet some problem.
I have search for a long time  and read some documents. But no use. 
Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
I want to achieve a function that get local ip and show it by using label when entering the interface.I don't understand how to deliver a variable from the"get_ip_address" to textvariable.

My os is Linux,python version is 2.7.

Here is some code:

```
import fcntl,struct,Tkinter,socket

def get_ip_address(ifname):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
              return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(),
                      0x8915,struct.pack('256s',
                      ifname[:15])
              )[20:24])
top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry('400x300+200+300')
ip_address = Tkinter.StringVar() 
ip_address.set(get_ip_address)
icon = top.iconbitmap('@/root/Downloads/python/sdju.xbm')
top.tk.call('wm','iconphoto',top._w,icon)
lable1 = Tkinter.Label(top,textvariable = ip_address)
lable1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: `ip_address.get(get_ip_address)`?!? didn't you mean `ip_address.set(get_ip_address)`?

Comment: did or didn't. In what way didnt it work? Be specific!!

Comment: you need to invoke the function with parentheses  ()

Comment: Thanks all of you！I have solve this problem！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

You are using `ip_address.get(get_ip_address)` getter functions generally take no arguments and any arguments given here will produce an error. What you want to do is set the value. So instead you need to call  `ip_address.set(get_ip_address)`.

The next issue is that you don't call `get_ip_address` you pass a reference to the function. So make sure you call it and the string will be set to it's return value and not a string representation of the function itself. You should pass the name of the network interface, you want the ip address for.

So `ip_address.set(get_ip_address)` becomes `ip_address.set(get_ip_address('lo'))`.

complete code:

```
import fcntl, struct, Tkinter, socket

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915,struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15]))[20:24])

top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry('400x300+200+300')
ip_address = Tkinter.StringVar()
ip_address.set(get_ip_address('lo'))

icon = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file='/root/Downloads/python/sdju.xbm')
top.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', top._w, icon)

lable1 = Tkinter.Label(top, textvariable=ip_address)
lable1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks！Sincerely！I have been studying this problem since last night,and read many documents,but still not understood.You really help me!

Comment: Yeah,I have upvote! i still can't set my own icon,i want to know if the "iconphoto"  in  `top.tk.call('wm','iconphoto',top.w,icon)` can replace by another type.It doesn't work by set `top.iconbitmap()`,and does it nessceary to use `tk.call()`?

Comment: @Pu1sar_ try that update. I'm on ubuntu and the icon shows in the task bar and not in the window itself. I don't know what you were expected?